# Variable interval for javascript setInterval based on number of inner loop iterations

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, recursion, setinterval

I'm trying to automate some actions on a webpage but running into some variable setInterval delay issues.  The code pulls a list of elements based on classname and iterates over each one performing an action which dynamically creates new elements on the page, once the elements in collection have been processed the code should re-pull the class elements and iterate over the new collection over and over again.

I want the main delay to be dependant on the number of class elements it pulls from the page and iterates over each time.  This code will be run on console in Chrome.

Here was my original working code without a variable delay:

```
var finishedActions = [];
var actionDelaySec = 5;
var totActionsInLoop;
setInterval( function() { 
    var pageElementsToActOn = document.getElementsByClassName('classname');
    totActions = pageElementsToActOn.length;
    for(var i =0; i < pageElementsToActOn.length; i++) {
        (function(i){
            window.setTimeout(function(){
                var actionText = pageElementsToActOn[i].textContent;
                if (finishedActions.indexOf(actionText) > -1) {
                    console.log("already finished action");
                } else {
                    finishedActions.push(actionText);
                    console.log(actionText);
                    pageElementsToActOn[i].click();
                }
            }, i * actionDelaySec * 1000);
        }(i));
    }
    console.log("New Loop");
}, 10000);
```

My first attempt to just change the 10000 figure to a variable caused a crash due to not being able to change setInterval delays while it's running.

After some research I thought I could recursively nest my function and call itself with a new delay each time.

This code also works but for some reason doesn't change the actual delay each time the main function is called but instead sets the delay to whatever is run on the first iteration:

```
var finishedActions = [];
var actionDelaySec = 160;
var totActionsInLoop = 5;
var totActionsMade = 0;
var myFunction = function(){
    var pageElementsToActOn = document.getElementsByClassName('classname');
    totActionsInLoop = pageElementsToActOn.length;
    for(var i =0; i < pageElementsToActOn.length; i++) {
        (function(i){
            window.setTimeout(function(){
                var actionText = pageElementsToActOn[i].textContent;
                if (finishedActions.indexOf(actionText) > -1) {
                    console.log("already finished action (" + actionText + ").");
                } else {
                    finishedActions.push(actionText);
                    console.log(actionText + " Connected At: " + timeStamp());
                    totActionsMade++;
                    pageElementsToActOn[i].click();
                }
            }, i * (actionDelaySec * 1000));
        }(i));
    }
    console.log("New Loop -- Actions on page: " + totActionsInLoop + "-- Total actions finished: " + totActionsMade + " -- Started At: " + timeStamp());
    setInterval(myFunction, (totActionsInLoop * (actionDelaySec * 1000)));
};
myFunction();
```

Can anyone explain to me why the delay isn't changing with each new function call and possibly help me fix the code to work as intended?

Thanks.

Comment: In your second example, `totActionsInLoop` is the only time related variable, but why would it change? That number comes from the number of elements with the class `classname`. For that number to change you would have to add or remove elements with that classname but you're not doing it in this function anywhere.

Comment: When the inner loop applies it's action on the class element, that element goes away and a new one dynamically replaces it so when the inner loop is called the next time it is iterating over all new elements.

Comment: Where? In this? `pageElementsToActOn[i].click()`

Comment: Yes by activating a click on the element it does an action outside of this code and removes the element from the page.  Sorry I didn't make that more clear in my question text.  I also realize I missed the click code in the first example given, will edit.

Comment: You should post that code. Also I just noticed that you're calling `setInterval` at the end.. In a recursive situation it's almost assured you meant `setTimeout`, it will call itself once, and again once, and again once. Right now it's going to trigger a new interval on every outer loop

Comment: In your first example, don't you have a syntax error? `var myFn = function () { .. }, 10000)`

Comment: Yes first one should have been setInterval without setting the function to a variable, fixed now.  In the second example I'll try it with window.setTimeout instead of setInterval.  There were other variations of code I've tested before asking the question where I tried that and it didn't work but not sure if I tried that with this version of the recursive code.  Thanks.

Comment: Changing setInterval to window.setTimeout seems to have fixed things.  If you'd like to provide it as an answer I'll accept it.  Thanks man.